# Replacing keys in a string with corresponding values from a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a dictionary with keys that look like this:

```
['NAME', 'ID', 'COURSE', 'DUE', 'SUBMITTED', 'MINUTESLATE', 'LATEDEDUCTION', 'P1', 'P1COMMENTS', 'P2', 'P2COMMENTS', 'SUBTOTAL', 'TOTAL']
```

My goal is to go through a file and replace occurrences of these keys with values that I've read in from another file. For instance:

```
Problem 1: <<P1>>/35 <<P1COMMENTS>>
```

would be replaced with something like:

```
Problem 1: 30/35 comment
```

However, I'm having issues with doing this, as the keys can be overlapping. I wrote this method using some code that I looked up previously for another assignment:

```
def replace_all(text, dic):
    for i, j in dic.items():
        text = text.replace(i, j)
    return text
```

However, this is the first time I've had overlapping keys in my dictionary, so I'm having a tough time tweaking this method to work properly. Currently, this is what my output looks like:

```
Problem 1: 30/35 30COMMENTS
```

Any ideas on a better way to approach this problem?

Comment: What do you mean, overlapping? Can you give an example?

Comment: Yes! So in that list of keys I gave, we have P1 and P1COMMENTS, but my function sees P1 over P1COMMENTS in some cases, since dictionaries aren't ordered. TOTAL and SUBTOTAL would be another example of this.

Comment: Does `Problem 1: <<P1>>/35 <<P1COMMENTS>>` have those `<< >>` surrounding the keys to be replaced? Or is it really Problem 1: P1/35 P1COMMENTS`?

Comment: If you have some idea of how the strings are structured, you should look into [regular expressions.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)

Comment: It does. Currently I'm calling replace() to get rid of those after calling my function. This works fine for non-overlapping keys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `re.sub()` to find each `<< key >>` and then replace it with the corresponding value from the dictionary.

```
import re

dct = {
  'P1': 30,
  'P1COMMENTS': 'comment'
}

print(dct)

s = 'Problem 1: <<P1>>/35 <<P1COMMENTS>>'
s = re.sub(r'<<(.*?)>>', lambda x: str(dct[x.group(1)]), s)
print(s)
```

Output:

```
Problem 1: 30/35 comment
```

Explanation:

`<<(.*?)>>`:

```
<<                // matches <<
  (               // start of group 1
    .*?           // matches any number (0 or more) of characters (lazy)
  )               // end of group 1
>>                // matches >>
```

[`re.sub()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub) will take a pattern, a replacement value, and a string, and will replace any pattern matches in the string, with the replacement value.  The function:

```
lambda x: str(dct[x.group(1)])
```

Will lookup the match in the dictionary, and return the value for the key.

Comment: Slick. Beat me to it. Mind explaining what `re`, `sub`, and `lambda` are/do, since this seems to be a homework assignment?

Comment: That gave me what I was looking for. Thanks for the explanation of what it actually does!

Comment: @jpruee happy to help!  If this answered your question, check out [What to do if someone answers my question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: You can even improve this by using [string.Template](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/string.html#template-strings). The key matching can be completely customized via regex groups.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a customizable [template engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_processor). Luckily, Python is shipped with [string.Template](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#template-strings).

```
import re
import string

class CustomTemplate(string.Template):
    pattern = r'<<(?P<named>[^>]+)>>'

template = '<<FOO>> 123456 <<FOOBAR>>tail'
print(CustomTemplate(template).substitute(
    FOO='foo_content',
    FOOBAR='foobar_stuff',
    ))
```

Output: `foo_content 123456 foobar_stufftail`